# What scaffold and models i need to cr8 RnR app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, crud, scaffold

I've got some database in .yml format and i don't understand what's scaffold and models i need to cr8 for this app.
.yml file:

```
users:
 - group: 'Admin'
   todo_list:
    - text: 'Create new user group'
      isCompleted: false
 - group: 'Moderator'
   todo_list:
    - text: 'Ban 2 or more users'
      isCompleted: false
 - group: 'User'
   todo_list:
    - text: 'create someone stupid question like this'
      isCompleted: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so this is what you will want to do:

```
rails g scaffold user toDo:text isComplete:boolean 

rails g scaffold moderator toDo:text isComplete:boolean 

rails g scaffold admin toDo:text isComplete:boolean
```

the scaffold command will generate all your templates for each item and give you a standard rails display for your CRUD Action

Each scaffold will create a model for each user type Admin, Moderator and User, it will also generate your controllers with basic functionality

once you have completed the scaffold generate you can go into app/db/migrations open them up and use `:default => false` to set the default value of the boolean (checkbox)

So your migration file should look like:

```
class AddUsers
  def up
    t.boolean :users, :isComplete, :default => true
  end
end

class AddModerators
  def up
    t.boolean :moderators, :isComplete, :default => true
  end
end

class AddAdmins
  def up
    t.boolean :admins, :isComplete, :default => true
  end
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it's actually like to do list, not user authorizations.

Comment: ok so do the user groups all have access to the same items on the list? im just confused about how this is supposed to be laid out.

Comment: it's just i've got 3 groups of users, and in each of this groups - to do list. I don't need to cr8 new users group, but i need to cr8 new task for 1 of this groups (admin, moderator, user);
Looks like:
{Admin
*task1;
*task2;
...
Moderator:
*task1;
*task2;
...
User:
*task1;
*task2;
...}

Comment: Answer has been updated to reflect your comment description